# Crash adding comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, global-inbox, ios-app

The SE iOS app crashes when adding comments to certain posts.

It was discovered to be if the "Add an Answer" button was visible, not just responding to a deleted comment.

Edited to match answer. Previous steps were not the only use case, and this error keeps getting re-reported in different ways.

Comment: What's with the downvote?

Comment: @mhlester I think this is related to a crash log I've received, which does crash on tapping Add Comment, but isn't caused by a deleted comment. I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of the bug was **tapping on "Add Comment"** while the "Add an answer' section was visible. This was causing an index out of bounds condition with logic that shows the "You are commenting on this answer" message.

You can confirm this by going to any question that has a relatively short, last answer (which allows you to fit the "add an answer" button on your screen as well), and then tapping on "Add Comment". I've tested the deleted comment scenario on my end, but there doesn't seem to be a problem.

However, your report did reveal some issues about tapping on comments/answers in the inbox for those that have been deleted, so stay tuned and keep reporting ;)

This crash will be fixed in build  0.1.17